# What Firebase Database structure is more appropriate? SWIFT 4, FIREBASE 5.0.0

Tags: swift, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, database-design

NOTE: Database = DB

NOTE: I'm using SWIFT 4 and Firebase 5.0.0

I am making a practice Instagram like project to practice using Firebase. I have tested the below 'DB 1' but then thought of 'DB 2' and was unsure about which one is more efficient and easier to code? The application is just supposed to upload a 'post' to a DB with 1 or 2 images. Thank you in advance!

EDIT:
Given that users would be able to see posts from people they follow and see posts from everyone on the search page. What would be an appropriate structure?

DB 1:

```
{
  "user1" : {
    "posts" : {
      "post1" : {
        "imgURL" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/datamodel2-52bdf.appspot.com/o/l@gmail.com%2Fpost1%2F19B28DCA-9CD1-4079-BC75-AB2981A64CE3?alt=media&token=d984d2bd-698e-4cf4-8e42-36bf277850f2"
      },
      "post2" : {
        "imgURL" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/datamodel2-52bdf.appspot.com/o/l@gmail.com%2Fpost1%2F19B28DCA-9CD1-4079-BC75-AB2981A64CE3?alt=media&token=d984d2bd-698e-4cf4-8e42-36bf277850f2"
      }
    },
    "userInfo" : {
      "email" : "exmple@gmail.com",
    }
  },
  "user2" : {
    "posts" : "allposts",
    "userInfo" : "email"
  }
}
```

DB 2:

```
    {
  "UserPosts" : {
    "User1ID" : {
      "Post1" : {
        "ImageURL1" : "URL"
      }
    }
  },
  "Users" : {
    "User1ID" : {
      "email" : "email"
    },
    "User2ID" : {
      "email" : "email"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You gonna store the passwords?!? ->:O

Comment: Now he won't!! .

Comment: Ya your right I wont, ill edit that out

Comment: Hehe :p why not use firestore?

Comment: @J.Doe why would I use that?

Comment: This is an impossible question to answer. Both structures are efficient and easy to code. However, that's NOT how to approach Firebase; You approach Firebase by asking *what do I want to get out of Firebase* and *What do I want to present to the user* along with *what will my queries be*? Those will determine the ultimate structure. Don't be afraid to try something and then back up and do it again if it's not working. I am going to vote to close because it's entirely to broad as it sits - we would need a lot more data to make any kind of recommendation about a structure.